# Unable to bind to an attached property in Windows 8 Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a attached property and it seems that it won't let me bind to an attach property in Windows 8. I can freely use this way in Silverlight/WPF but I don't know why it won't let me. A post in MSDN Forum said it was fixed through Windows 8 Release, I have the release now but it won't work. It says "Value does not fall within the expected range"..

```
    public static class CountHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Title", typeof (string), typeof (CountHelper), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public static void SetTitle(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetTitle(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(TitleProperty);
    }
}
```

XAML file

```
    <TextBlock local:CountHelper.Title="Hello"  Text="{Binding Path=(local:CountHelper.Title)}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your DataContext? Perhaps you should add ElementName property to your binding to set the context to your control.

*EDIT - this works fine for me:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App75
{
    public static class CountHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Title", typeof(string), typeof(CountHelper), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public static void SetTitle(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            element.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }

        public static string GetTitle(UIElement element)
        {
            return (string)element.GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}


<Page
    x:Class="App75.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App75"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="tb"
            local:CountHelper.Title="Hello"
            Text="{Binding Path=(local:CountHelper.Title), ElementName=tb}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: So you're saying it should be like this "Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBlockName, Path=(local:CountHelper.Title)}"/>" ?

Comment: I think so, assuming your TextBlock definition has a x:Name="TextBlockName" attribute. Otherwise your binding to a void... or whatever the DataContext is.

Comment: There's no difference if I bind it to itself any why did Microsoft did this thing?

Comment: I copied exact example you have. Still gives me the "Value does not fall within expected range"

Comment: Can you try a separate project? Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: How would it be elsewhere in the code though, it's just attach property and the built in control of Microsoft.

Comment: Ok, I just did a clean project with your example. Did not work, same error.

Comment: Update : It looks like it works when you just ignore the error. But I wonder why it's giving me a compile error like that if it will work anyway.

Comment: Oh, perhaps it's just a XAML designer error. It is notoriously bad. I actually rarely look at the errors/warnings window for that reason and if I do - I close all open xaml files to see it clearly.